# AVD error in Android Studio 2.1.1

Tags: android-studio

When I run the AVD in Android Studio 2.1.1 I get the following error

Open the vm device error:\.\hax_vm00, ec:2
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
Failed to open vm 0
Failed to create HAX VM
No accelerator found.
failed to initialize HAX: Invalid argument

I searched the internet about this error and **tried nearly all the suggested procedures** but could not fix the problem so far. Is there a way to fix this?
System images with armeabi work ok. Operating system is windows 8.1.PC has an Intel CPU with VT-x enabled.